# Updating information on a MySQL database from a PHP site

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

I've been trying all kinds of tutorials and solutions on here and I can not get this to work. Please help! 
 

** **UPDATE #1** **

This is the error that I receive when running my code: "***Error occured in the insert: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1***"

** **UPDATE #2** **

Here is the page that shows everything in the table:
editBrowse.php

`

```
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM inventory";
  $result = $connection->query($sql);

  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      echo "
      <img src=$row[image] id='productImage'> <br>
      product: $row[product] <br>
      category: $row[category] <br>
      seller: $row[seller] <br>
      <a href='edit.php?id=$row[id]'>Edit</a>
      <hr>
      ";
    }
  } else {
    echo "No Results";
  }
  $connection->close();
```

`

This is the page that shows up when you click the edit button above: edit.php

`

```
  <?php
  // Connection code..etc..


  $sql = "SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE id=".$_REQUEST['id'];
  $result = $connection->query($sql);

  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
  } else {
    echo "No Results";
  }
  $connection->close();

?>



<div class="row" id="mainSection">

  <form action="update.php" method="post">

    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$id?>">

    <h3>Image:</h3>
        <input type="text" name="image" value="<?=$row['image']?>">

    <h3>Product:</h3>
        <input type="text" name="product" value="<?=$row['product']?>">

    <h3>Category:</h3>
        <input type="text" name="category" value="<?=$row['category']?>">

    <h3>Seller:</h3>
        <input type="text" name="seller" value="<?=$row['seller']?>">

    <br>
    <br>

    <input type="submit" value="Update My Record">

  </form>
  <br>
  <a href="admin.php" id="backButton">Back</a>

</div>
```

`

And this is the file that runs when you click the "Update My Record" button above: update.php

'

```
$id= $_POST['id'];
$image = $_POST['image'];
$product = $_POST['product'];
$category = $_POST['category'];
$seller = $_POST['seller'];



$sql = "UPDATE inventory set image='$image', product='$product', category='$category', seller='$seller' WHERE id = $id";


if ($connection->query($sql) === true) {
  echo "Inserted Successfully";
} else {
  echo "Error occured in the insert: " . $connection->error;
}

 $connection->close();
```

'

Comment: You are using incorrect syntax. Look for a few examples of the `UPDATE` syntax.

Comment: As mentioned elsewhere, you're using an INSERT syntax for an UPDATE statement. You need to change this. You're also at risk for SQL-injection if you pass variables directly to the query. I would look at prepared statements: MySQLi http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php or PDO http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: You might be missing some values and/or not have default values set. Can you echo $sql in your else statement so we can see the exact query it's trying to run? echo 'Error occurred: ' . $connection->error . ' in query: ' . $sql;

Comment: @versalle88 Got it figured out, thanks though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a syntactic problem in your sql:

```
$sql = "UPDATE inventory set image='$image', product='$product', category='$category', seller='$seller' WHERE id = $id";
```

In addition you need to verify if $id has the correct value. Because if it's empty or null your query will fail.

If you want to insert data you can use a query like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO inventory (image, product, category, seller) VALUES ('$image', '$product', '$category', '$seller')";
```

Try this in your edit.php view:

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE id=".$_REQUEST['id];
      $result = $connection->query($sql);

      if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
      } else {
        echo "No Results";
      }
      $connection->close();
?>
<div class="row" id="mainSection">
  <form action="update.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="value="<?php echo $row['id']?>"">
    <h3>Image:</h3>
        <input type="text" name="image" value="<?php echo $row['image']?>">
    <h3>Product:</h3>
        <input type="text" name="product" value="<?php echo $row['product']?>">
    <h3>Category:</h3>
        <input type="text" name="category" value="<?php echo $row['category']?>">
    <h3>Seller:</h3>
        <input type="text" name="seller" value="<?php echo $row['seller']?>">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Update My Record">
  </form>
  <br>
  <a href="admin.php" id="backButton">Back</a>    
</div>
```

Comment: I updated the 3 block of code to show everything. I left out a part on accident.

Comment: You have to set it's value in your form <input type="hidden" name="id" value="232332"> of <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$id?>"> where the $id is a value is comes from a select query

Comment: Ok you have to pass $id as a parameter to your edit.php view like this: edit.php?id=$row[id] and then in your edit.php view you need to do a select to retrieve the data corresponding to that row and set all values to your form elements

Comment: I updated the whole post to show my code with the changes you've told me and with the new error. The only thing I haven't added is the "select" you told me to do in my edit.php and setting all the values in my form elements. Could you explain further? Sorry I am very new to this, trying to learn.

Comment: Did the last update, it's better now because it displays the info that is already in the database in the fields to edit them. When I press the update button it still comes up with that same error above, I updated everything in my post for you to see.

Comment: Replace <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$id?>"> with <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']?>">

Comment: I replaced the code, everything seems to be running but the information isn't actually updating to the table.. I think it's something I need in my update.php file? I really don't know.

Comment: Use echo $sql; die(); to see your query value.

Comment: Where do I put that? I'm assuming in update.php but don't know how to use it.

Comment: I used that and it comes up with a blank page.

Comment: use var_dump($sql) instead of echo $sql, you can also view the page source html code from your browser

Comment: I used `var_dump($sql)` and this is what came out: `string(185) "UPDATE inventory set image='https://02varvara.files.wordpress.com/2012/05/00b-street-art-athens-05-12.jpg', product='Athens', category='Painting', seller='Julie Varat' WHERE id = '.12.'" Inserted Successfully`

Comment: If the id is an integer you have to remove '..' it must be id=12

Comment: Took the periods out, it now returns `string(183) "UPDATE inventory set image='https://02varvara.files.wordpress.com/2012/05/00b-street-art-athens-05-12.jpg', product='Athens', category='Painting', seller='Julie Varat' WHERE id = '12'" Inserted Successfully`

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM inventory";
  $result = $connection->query($sql);

  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      echo "
      <img src=$row['image'] id='productImage'> <br>
      product: $row['product'];<br>
      category: $row['category']; <br>
      seller: $row['seller'] ;<br>
      <a href="edit.php?id=$row['id']">Edit</a>
      <hr>
      ";
    }
  } else {
    echo "No Results";
  }
  $connection->close();
```

**EDIT.PHP**

```
<div class="row" id="mainSection">
  <?php $id = $_REQUEST['id']; ?>
  <form action="update.php" method="post">

    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$id?>">

    <h3>Image:</h3>
        <input type="text" name="image">

    <h3>Product:</h3>
        <input type="text" name="product">

    <h3>Category:</h3>
        <input type="text" name="category">

    <h3>Seller:</h3>
        <input type="text" name="seller">

    <br>
    <br>

    <input type="submit" value="Update My Record">

  </form>
  <br>
  <a href="admin.php" id="backButton">Back</a>

</div>
```

**UPDATE.PHP**

```
<?php
$id= $_POST['id'];
$image = $_POST['image'];
$product = $_POST['product'];
$category = $_POST['category'];
$seller = $_POST['seller'];

$sql = "UPDATE inventory set image='".$image."', product='".$product."', category='".$category."', seller='".$seller."' WHERE id = ".$id." ";

if ($connection->query($sql) === true) {
  echo "Inserted Successfully";
} else {
  echo "Error occured in the insert: " . $connection->error;
}

 $connection->close();
```

Comment: This gets rid of the error, thank you! But when I go through updating it, it says it ran successfully , but nothing is updated in the table?

Comment: try `print_r($_POST);`& check all values are coming or not.

Comment: Where do I put `print_r($_POST);` ?

Comment: Sorry, I think I am still putting `print_r($_POST);` in the wrong spot. The table isn't updating but on the success page its showing all the information I entered. Could you update the "update.php" section of your answer so I can see? I apologize I'm very new at programming.

Comment: Thank you for all your help, I've got it figured out now. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a value for the `id`, and then use `$_POST['id']` in your query.

Comment: I updated the third block of code to show everything, I left out a part on accident. "$id= $_POST['id'];" should be what sets that right?

Answer (score 0):

First of all the sql syntax for update query is wrong. Secondly there is no value set in the id in the form. So when you post the form the value will be empty.

Comment: What is the correct syntax for update? And I thought "value="<?=$id?>" in the form sets the value for id?